# File read from second spider got trunced

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I'm using scrapy to scrape some data.
i got 2 spiders = spider a and b

spider a fetches some data and write it to a file.
spider b reads that data.

the problem is that spider b gets an empty file.

I can see that the file is filled after spider a finishes hes job.

I spent few hour to figure this out.

code snippet:

## spider a

```
f = open('file.txt', 'a+')
f.write("str")
f.write("\n")
f.close()
```

## spider b

```
f = open('file.txt')
for line in f:
  print line
f.close()
```

Nothing comes out, what is wrong with this?

EDIT:I got it to work.
I open a file with 'a'
write a line and then close the file.
this goes for all lines.

the code snippet was revised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) You want `f.close()` instead of `f.close` in "spider b". The way it is now, you are *not* properly closing the file, so its buffers aren't getting flushed.

Also, regarding your use of [f.flush()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=flush#file.flush) in "spider a" be sure you are aware of this note from the documentation:

> Note flush() does not necessarily write the file’s data to disk. Use
>   **flush()** followed by **os.fsync()** to ensure this behavior.

In fact, unless you have a good reason, it might be better to just `close()` the file. If you do have/want to flush it, be sure you also use [os.sfsync()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.fsync).

(2) Also, instead of

```
for line in f:
   print f
```

try this:

```
for line in f:
   print line
```

As a final note, take a look at using `with` to manage open files. For instance

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
   # put file related actions here
   for line in f:
      print line
```

will automatically close the file at the end of the block for you or if an exception is encountered.

Comment: Yeah, rather than trusting `flush` I'd simply close the file.

Comment: @DSM yes, agreed, that's usually the better approach, unless for some reason the file needs to remain open (can't think of a good example for this though)

Comment: I think this is related to a missing close in spider a.
I did not find the right state to close it.
I want to close it when all requests have been completed.
Is there a way to know such thing?
i tried the __del__ function, but this did not do the trick.

when I try to read a file spider A did not create, spider b produced the right behavior.

Comment: I got it to work.
I open a file with 'a'
write a line and then close the file.

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't show any problems, except of two typos you've made with `f.close()` and `print line`. My guess is in your real code you try to iterate through file in b, then wait for a to add more data, and then b tries to continue interation. You can't do it. If iterator hit the end, it can't resume. Easiest way to get around this is to rewrite your code using f.readline():

```
while True:
    line = f.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    print line
```